# SQL Server : execute dynamic sql help please

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
            @DynamicSQL
        ,   N'@HostIDs VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
        ,   @HostIDs OUTPUT;

PRINT @HostIDs;

SELECT @HostIDs AS HostIDs;
SET @UpdateSQL = '
            EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_Win7_HostUpdater_NEW]
            @HostID = ''' + @HostIDs + ''' , 
            @PackageID = ''' + @PackageID  + ''' , 
            @MigrationFlag = ''' + @MigrationFlagID + ''' , 
            @Manufacturer = ' + @Manufacturer + ' , 
            @Product = ' + @Product + ' , 
            @Version = ' + @Version + ' ,
            @Reason = ' + @Reason + ' ,
            @Contact = ' + @Contact + '
        ';

        SELECT @UpdateSQL AS UpdateSQL;
        PRINT @UpdateSQL;           
        EXEC( @UpdateSQL )  
  END
```

I have a stored procedure on both a SQL Server 2005 and 2008 in which the above code is the last part of

it returns a `VARCHAR(MAX)` of numbers separated by commas.

Now this returned value is large upwards of 600k characters. If I execute this on a SQL Server 2005 it works like 50% of the time, `@HostIDs` is populated always and `@UpdateSQL` gets generated with the correct values and is executed.

On SQL Server 2008, `@HostIDs` is populated but `@UpdateSQL` is always NULL

This is weirding me out tremendously

Can anyone maybe shed some light on my odd problem?

Comment: Probably one of the other variables is `NULL`. Did you test all of them?

Comment: Why do you need to create the `@UpdateSQL` in the first place? (It just looks like a target for SQL injection.) Why do you not just have the command as an actual statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
select 'abc' + null + 'def'
--- abcdef

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
select 'abc' + null + 'def'
--- NULL
```

That's one way to get around the problem, which is to set it off before your string building and back on after.  Any NULL in the sequence of string concatenation renders the entire statement NULL, which explains `it works like 50% of the time` - these are when all of the variables are non-null.

Completely agree with freefaller though, unless the question's an abstraction of a larger puzzle, there's no reason to build a dynamic SQL and EXEC it when a direct execution will work for the particular snippet shown.

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know about this feature! Does it perform better than doing an ISNULL? It won't work for this question because it probably needs to insert the value null in null cases, and not cause an empty string, but I could definitely have used this feature once or twice in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the parameters are null, the entire statement will be null. You can work around it by doing something like this (and I don't know what the data types are, but sometimes you need to cast them to varchar from int/bool/etc. types to make the concatenation work):

```
SET @UpdateSQL = '
            EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_Win7_HostUpdater_NEW]
            @HostID = ' + ISNULL('''' + @HostIDs + '''', 'null') + ' , 
            @PackageID = ' + ISNULL('''' + @PackageID + '''', 'null')  + ' , 
            @MigrationFlag = ' + ISNULL('''' + @MigrationFlagID + '''', 'null') + ' , 
            @Manufacturer = ' + ISNULL(@Manufacturer, 'null') + ' , 
            @Product = ' + ISNULL(@Product, 'null') + ' , 
            @Version = ' + ISNULL(@Version, 'null') + ' ,
            @Reason = ' + ISNULL(@Reason, 'null') + ' ,
            @Contact = ' + ISNULL(@Contact, 'null') + '
        ';
```

Comment: thank you... I didn't know if one was null the whole thing would be null

Answer (score 0):

It causes because you are  not handling nulls

you can use   sp_executesql    instead of exec  it has  some benefits  over exec